# Extend class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This code is working fine.

```
class ArInvHeader < ActiveRecord

  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES = {
    :shipto_customer_address => _("Ship to customer address ")
  }

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr,options={})
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
  end

end
```

I want to put this method in common file and use it in every model.

```
def self.human_attribute_name(attr,options={})
  HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
end
```

How may i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing that you wish to use `human_attribute_name` for all subclasses of `ActiveRecord::Base` - if that's the case, it's just a matter of extending `ActiveRecord::Base` with that method, so that it is available to all its subclasses: just open the class, define the method, and you're good to go:

```
class ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.human_attribute_name(attr,options={})
    HUMANIZED_ATTRIBUTES[attr.to_sym] || super
  end

end
```

Just place this on `config/initializers/active_record.rb`, and it will be automatically required by the application.

Alternatively, you can use the i18n tools present in rails to achieve a similar result - assuming your locale is `en`:

```
# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      ar_inv_header:
        shipto_customer_address: "Ship to customer address "
```

That way, you can just call `ArInvHeader.human_attribute_name(:shipto_customer_address)`. This is the preferred way to change the "human names" of ActiveRecord models and attributes.

Comment: Yes i did the same thing and it's working fine. But is it a preferred way to do it?

Comment: I think it's the cleanest way to do it - and how most people do it, really. If you take a look at some gems that somehow extend the basic functionality of Rails models (acts_as_*, e.g.), you can see the same pattern applied. Read this: http://yehudakatz.com/2009/11/12/better-ruby-idioms/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try locale.yml for this functionality?

Comment: What i need to modify for it?

Answer (score 0):

You can put it on your application_controller and use this line:

```
helper_method :human_attribute_name
```

Now you can use it across the system